# Angular Polymorphism Broken in Templates?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a base class, and another class that extends it.

```typescript
export class Person {
    public name: string;
    public age: number;
}

export class Teacher extends Person {
    public yearsTeaching: number;
}
```

In my component I want to display a list of people, some of whom will be Teachers:

```typescript
public people: Person[] = [
  {
    name: 'Joe Student',
    age: 13
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane Student',
    age: 11
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill the Teacher',
    age: 33,
    yearsTeaching: 5
  }
];
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let person of people">
    <div>Name: {{person.name}}</div>
    <div>Age: {{person.age}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="person.yearsTeaching">Years Teaching: {{person.yearsTeaching}}</div>
</div>
```

This used to work, but no longer in Angular 16.  I now get the error: "Property 'yearsTeaching' does not exist on type 'Person'"

What is the correct way to do this?  I'd prefer not to put a bunch of typeof checks inside my template.

I'm also curious if this behavior is a function of a tsconfig.json setting.

Comment: Update: setting the tsconfig option "strictTemplates" to false does indeed fix the problem, but it also completely disables any template type checking.  The behavior that I'm looking for is not that, but rather it should continue to do template type checking, but allow for polymorphism.  In my prior Angular 13 version of the app, this is exactly what I got.

Comment: Well, a `Teacher` is a `Person`, but a `Person` isn't necessarily a `Teacher`. That's why the error. To solve this try to define the `people` array with an union type: `Person[] | Teacher[]`.

Comment: (Person | Teached)[] should be used.

Comment: There is always `$any(myVar)` use can use in templates to escape the typechecker

Comment: You could use a [`InstanceOf`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs%2Fmintplayer-ng-bootstrap%2Finstance-of%2Fsrc) pipe, but then you need to explicitly [call the constructors](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/advanced/instance-of/instance-of.component.ts#L10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way to do this? I'd prefer not to put a bunch of typeof checks inside my template.

Here are two options.

#### 1. Use `undefined` to separate the two types `Person` vs. `Teacher`.

```js
type Person = {
  name: string;
  yearsOfTeaching: undefined;
};

//Omit takes all the properties from Person and omits yearsOfTeaching
type Teacher = Omit<Person, 'yearsOfTeaching'> & {
  yearsOfTeaching: number;
};

type People = Person | Teacher;

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ExampleComponent {

  public people: People [] = [
    {name: 'John', yearsOfTeaching: undefined},
    {name: 'Jack', yearsOfTeaching: 2}
  ];
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let person of people">
  <div>{{person.name}}</div>
  <div *ngIf="person.yearsOfTeaching !== undefined">{{person.yearsOfTeaching}}</div>
</div>
```

In this version, `Person` will always have `yearsOfTeaching: undefined` while `Teacher` will always have `yearsOfTeaching: SOME_NUMBER`. Because they both have `yearsOfTeaching` property, you just need to do a normal `undefined` check.

Note that I do an explicit check for `person.yearsOfTeaching !== undefined` to avoid the truthiness pitfall where `0` is evaluated to `false`.

---

##### 2. Use a flag of literal string type to separate the two.

```js
type Person = {
  kind: 'person',
  name: string;
};

type Teacher = Omit<Person, 'kind'> & {
  kind: 'teacher';
  yearsOfTeaching: number;
};

type People = Person | Teacher;

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ExampleComponent {

  public people: People [] = [
    {kind: 'person', name: 'John'},
    {kind: 'teacher', name: 'Jack', yearsOfTeaching: 2}
  ];
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let person of people">
  <div>{{person.name}}</div>
  <div *ngIf="person.kind === 'teacher'">{{person.yearsOfTeaching}}</div>
</div>
```

In this version, both `Person` and `Teacher` have a `kind` property. The value of the `kind` is different for each of them. `Person` has a `kind: 'person'` while `Teacher` has a `kind: 'teacher'`. This `kind` property helps compiler to understand that they are of different types.